# Template Matching when image is partially off screen?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

How can one achieve template matching when the target object is partially off the screen? Specifically, I'm trying to find a snake in a picture, but only its tail is visible, the rest of the body was clipped out of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this task is more texture segmentation task then template matching.

Something like that: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suyash/Dissertation_html/node78.html